# HTML - scroll to bottom of div when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div that has a lot of content in it, and just the div scrolls vertically.

I have something at the bottom of the div that needs to be easy to get to. I cannot move it out of the div though.

Is there a link I can use, or some javasript, to make it scroll to the bottom of the div when the link is clicked?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any JavaScript for this. HTML has the means to do this built in. You can use [name anchors](http://freepages.computers.rootsweb.ancestry.com/~pasher/anchors.htm) to jump to portions of the page without reloading the document.

```
<div>
    <p>
        Lots of content
    </p>
    <a href="#importantplace">click this link to get to the bottom of the div</a>
    <p>
        Lots of content
    </p>
    <p id="importantpplace">
        Important content
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Tip! for others reading Johns answer an ID attribute can be used with almost any element so you can use ID instead of NAME

Comment: I would also like to suggest using `id` instead of `name` and definitely skip the empty `a` element.

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly. Thank you for the suggestions.